# How come when updating the display driver, a command line briefly shows

Tags: windows-7, display-driver

***This is not a problem or anything I am struggling with. It's simply just making me curious.***

How come when updating my display driver, a blank command-line shows briefly, before the desktop shows up again? I suspect this may boil down to how a display driver works in the first place?

If it makes any difference, I notice this when I update my nVidia display driver.

**Edit**
I do not mean a command-line *window*. The desktop disappears, replaced by a full-screen, blank, command-line. The screen goes black, with an underscore blinking. After 1-3 seconds, the desktop re-appears by itself.

Comment: I imagine it is shelling out to run regsvr32 to register new DLLs. I'm not putting this as an answer since there isn't any definitive way for us to tell you exactly what is happening on your machine.

Comment: @EBGreen I apologize, I wasn't clear enough. Please see my edits.

Comment: Does it goa away by itself?

Comment: @EBGreen Yeah, it does.

Comment: use process explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what the process is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is restarting the video driver, kind of hard to display a rendered desktop while trying to restart the software rendering the desktop!

There is a basic text driver built in to the BIOS (all the stuff you see before windows boots is rendered by that) windows is dropping to that, replacing the code that was in use and in memory, then restarting it.